# Mod Coder Pack for minecraft 1.8.8 failed to decompile

Tags: java, decompile

I tried to decompile minecraft 1.8.8 using MCP918 and I have an error that I cannot fix.

Here are the logs:

https://zerobin.net/?07c9671c16bc4011#g6co8FZc8RJkkQiPb6pu65HixcEORkWZGN8qHPXkHew=

Some informations:

> Java development kit version:11
> Os: windows 11

Comment: Please do not place data on external sites that is necessary to understand the question. In a few weeks the external link is broken and your question is useless for the community as it can not be understood anymore. Always include the most relevant parts into your question. What Java decompilers have you tried? There are quite a few Java decompilers available.

Comment: I used the modcoderpack decompiler, because it's made just for minecraft decompiling

Comment: Then you should contact the developers of MCP918 and ask why decompiling fails.